# System.NullReferenceException: "Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt." when adding a definded string to a List

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to add a string from a List, to another List. After getting a NullReferenceException I tried to print out the content of the string. Its NOT Null. That's Why I cant understand why I'm getting this Exception.

```
foreach (string s in EntrieDatasReady)
{
    if (s.Contains("["))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        CategoryList.Add(s);
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

Before Crashing the application he gives me this Output:

[image: 1]

So the Exception seems to appear when I'm trying to add the string to the List. This is not understandable to me. Because obviously "s" is not "Null".

My Code:

[image: 2]

Comment: _"Because obviously "s" is not "Null""_ - Why "obviously"?

Comment: Also you have other stuff in your code which can be null. Especially taking in account that first `MessageBox` seems to be showing =)

Comment: If your test is correct, it means `CategoryList` is null. (note though, that if `s` is null, the if statement will already fail on `c.Contains`

Comment: CategoryList is a public List, with the Addition { get; private set; }. So maybe the Add function gives null... but why? i'm sorry for this question I'm just an apprentice since about one month.

Comment: @MHerbst How do you initialize that `CategoryList`?

Comment: Is it ever created? if the property is only declared, it will be null. You could have it automatically create an instance in the getter if null, or always have a default instance, e.g. `public List<string> CategoryList { get; private set; } = new List<string>();`

Comment: @AKX public List<string> CategoryList { get; private set; }

Comment: @Me.Name OMG thank you so much. I'm just so stupid. forgot the = new List function.

Comment: @AKX unfortunately it just showed me that message. It didnt reffered to any Code.

Comment: Then you didn't use the debugger correctly. It will definitely show you the line where the exception happens, and you can use its tools to view variable values.

Comment: Im trying my best to learn, I'm just a beginner programming in this company for like 2 weeks. Thabks for your help :)